# What is this "vvk" or "AAk" hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

A dietary supplement claims to be kosher:

[image: vitamin label]

The Ⓥ is probably to indicate it is vegan, and isn't the hechsher of the Vaad Hoeir of Saint Louis, but the <sub>ᓫ</sub> remains a mystery.

I've checked all the lists listed at https://www.koshermarks.com/recommended-lists but didn't find it.

Comment: Who manufactures it?

Comment: @Dov Well, it says [Approved Vitamins](https://approvedvitamins.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the hechsher of Rabbi A Adler of Gateshead UK, see

http://www.hechshers.info/kashauth/147.htm